# How to invoke browser to open "about:blank"

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

Using C code, how to invoke the default browser to open "about:blank" (a blank page)?

I've tried many methods, here are some that don't work:

1. Call `<Windows.h>`'s `ShellExecuteW` or `ShellExecute` passing `"open"` as its 2nd argument
2. As method 1, but use `http:about:blank` instead

Results:

1. As "about:blank" contains no "http:" or "https:", so Windows doesn't know to invoke the browser.
2. The browser will open, but results in a default page instead of a blank page

What's more, using something like `http:about:blank` or `http://about:blank` may be not correct.

Maybe the only valid url pointing to a blank is `about:blank`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that `AssocQueryString` helps (requiring to link against `shlwapi.dll`),

This is [`AssocQueryStringW`'s reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shlwapi/nf-shlwapi-assocquerystringw)

Here is one possible version of `C++` code:

```cpp
#include<shlwapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32.lib")

#define F_ASSOC ASSOCF_NONE
#define assoc(buffer, sizep) ::AssocQueryStringW(F_ASSOC, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE,\
   L"http", L"open", (buffer), (sizep))

DWORD getDefaultBrowser(LPWSTR &pszPath){
    DWORD size = 0;
    assoc(NULL, &size); // get required buffer size, returns S_FALSE
    pszPath = new WCHAR[size];
    HRESULT hr = assoc(pszPath,&size); // assert(hr==S_OK);
    return size;
    // remember `delete[]pszPath;`
}

int main(){
    LPWSTR browserPath;
    DWORD len = getDefaultBrowser(browserPath);
    if (len == 0)return -1;

    ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", browserPath, L"about:blank", NULL, SW_SHOW);

    delete[] browserPath;
}
```

---

Also, corresponding `C` code:

```c
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<Windows.h>
#include<shlwapi.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Shlwapi.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "Shell32.lib")

#define F_ASSOC ASSOCF_NONE
#define assoc(buffer, sizep) AssocQueryStringW(F_ASSOC, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, \
    L"http", L"open", (buffer), (sizep));
DWORD getDefaultBrowser(LPWSTR* pOut){
    DWORD size = 0;
    assoc(NULL, &size); // get required buffer size, returns S_FALSE
    *pOut = (LPWSTR)malloc(size * sizeof(WCHAR));
    HRESULT hr = assoc(*pOut,&size); // assert(hr==S_OK);
    return size;
    // remember `free(pOut);`
}
int main(){
    //Get default web browser path
    LPWSTR browserPath;
    DWORD len = getDefaultBrowser(&browserPath); 
    if(len == 0) return -1;

    ShellExecuteW(NULL, L"open", browserPath, L"about:blank", NULL, SW_SHOW);

    free(browserPath);
}
```

Comment: In addition, a similar functionality can be gained when defining `assoc` as  `AssocQueryStringW(F_ASSOC, ASSOCSTR_EXECUTABLE, L"http", L"open", (buffer), (sizep));`

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me a while ago, might still be working

```
ShellExecute(nullptr, "open", "http:", nullptr, nullptr, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Comment: However, it won't open a blank page but a default page

Comment: If it does not work, then it seems there is no other way except getting the default system registry value in `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command`.

Comment: As I try, this would return IExplore, instead of Edge, taking my computer as an example.

Comment: It may be a stub for old applications that may attempt to run IExplore but run Edge. What is purpose of running a blank page? If you then connect the tab and navigate to another content, does it matter if it's a default page?

Comment: Sure. Thanks. It's cause I'm fixing some existing code, documented to open a blank page. To avoid complexity, now I think it's better to change its document.